# Badges are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

From a user perspective, I cannot gather any evidence, but from my experience with other Stack Exchange sites, I would say that badges are broken on this site.

Many badges, such as Critic, Editor, Student, or Teacher, should have been awarded to many users; however, the only badge I can see is Informed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally, this was caused by the same issue as the [close vote reviews not appearing](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9).

Scheduled routes are back in action, so you should see badges awarded as expected. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you! Does this also apply badges retroactively?

Comment: @Afr Yes, the badges will be awarded retroactively. It should have already happened by now, but you see any that appear to be missing, let me know.